# Wave Equation: what do Characteristic Curves mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, characteristics

This is my question:

> 3. Compute the characteristic curves of the following wave equation
>      $$
>    \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}-a^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}=0
>    $$
>      and draw them on an $x-t$ coordinate system.

I couldn't figure out what "charachteristic curves" means. I found solutions about wave quation but couldn't found anything about this "characteristic curve". I will appreciate any help.

Thanks for your care, (Stay home and keep dealing with math )

Comment: I typed up your question, please do it in the future, you can learn how from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thx a lot! I'm new here so I will pay attention to this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wave equation has the following general solution (in your notation)

$$u(x,t) = A\sin(kx-\omega t)$$

Here, $k$ would denote the wavenumber in $m^{-1}$, and omega the wave frequency in $rad/s$, such that

$$a = w/k$$

Now, a characteristic for a wave is the plane along which there is a constant deflection wrt both space and time, i.e, it would correspond to the following family of planes

$$x-at = c$$

Where c is a constant. The physical intuition of defining these being how you would define a wavefront. If you study acoustics or any wave propagation, a wave is drawn as it's characteristic planes. This allows you to visualise the geometry of the wave, and is especially useful for boundary conditions and reflection/refraction

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to reach the solution!

Comment: @MathInSpace General solutions deduced from the characteristics are rather of the form $u = F(x-at) + G(x+at)$. Characteristic curves are of the form $x\pm at=c$.